# What was on the whiteboard during the Futurama Live Q&A?

Tags: futurama

[image: Image of whiteboard with alienese]

During the [Futurama Live Q&A](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1908/futurama-week-qa-event-on-july-11th?cb=1), there was a message written in one of Futurama's alien languages in the background.  What does it say?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

using [this](http://www.gotfuturama.com/Interactive/AlienCodec/) I got :

```
EMAIL
THEZAXXAR@GMAIL.COM
AND YOU MIGHT
WIN A PRIZE!
```

By the end of the [show](http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/23929909/highlight/275846) (see at 1:00:35), they recived around 50 email and drafted 5, the prize was :

[image: a hypno frog]

Comment: That's a stupid pri... *(BWAAAAAAAAAAAAA!)* ALL GLORY TO THE HYPNOTOAD!